# Convert String to a Font Icon type UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, char, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP application that calls an API. The API returns a `Glyph` code from the `MDL2 Assets` based on the content. e.g.

```
{
    "content": "Line",
    "glyph": "F7B4"
}
```

Now I know to show a glyph from c# we need to use `\uF7B4` but here the issue is that the API cannot return a `\uF7B4` instead of `"F7B4"`. Is there any way I can make this *conversion*?

Comment: `(char)(Convert.ToInt32("F7B4", 16))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Convert`ing as follow:

```
 string glyph = "F7B4";

 char result = (char)(Convert.ToInt32(glyph, 16)); // '\uF7B4'
```